# Extracting total value of a tuple

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I'm very new to Python, so please forgive my ignorance. I'm trying to calculate the total number of energy units in a system. For example, the Omega here will output both (0,0,0,1) and (2,2,2,1) along with a whole lot of other tuples. I want to extract from Omega how many tuples have a total value of 1 (like the first example) and how many have a total value of 7 (like the second example). How do I achieve this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import product

N = 4 ##The number of Oscillators
q = range(3) ## Range of number of possible energy units per oscillator


Omega = product(q, repeat = N)
print(list(product(q, repeat = N)))
```

Comment: you can use `filter` or list comprehension to achieve this, for example, `[tup for tup in Omega if sum(tup) == 1]`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Omega = product(q, repeat = N)
l = list(product(q, repeat = N))
l1 = [i for i in l if sum(i)==1]
l2 = [i for i in l if sum(i)==7]
print(l1,l2)
```

Comment: You never used the first line. The 2nd line is superfluous - you may use directly `Omega` instead of `l` in the next 2 lines. BTW, the name `Omega` (with capital `O`) doesn't conform [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). Use `omega` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `sum()` on tuples as well as lists of integers/numbers.

Now you say omega is a list of tuples, is that correct?  Something like

`Omega = [(0,0,0,1), (2,2,2,1), ...)]`

In that case I think you can do

`sums_to_1 = [int_tuple for int_tuple in omega if sum(int_tuple) == 1]`

If you want to have some default value for the tuples that don't sum to one you can put the if statement in the list comprehension in the beginning and do

`sums_to_1 = [int_tuple if sum(int_tuple) == 1 else 'SomeDefaultValue' for int_tuple in omega]`

Comment: I checked it out and it's true.  Apparnetly importing numpy certain ways overwrites the sum() function though I don't believe op needs to worry about that unless he does have a `from numpy import *` somewhere in which case sum can get funky.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552458/python-sum-has-a-different-result-after-importing-numpy

Comment: Then you will give the OP greater confidence in your answer if you omit the "believe" and "think". That is what I think, anyway.

Comment: You probably don't try to run your code. If you fix it (change the first `Omega` to `omega`) and remove the phrases "I believe" and "I think", I'll vote up your answer.